# Weird jumping of polygon object

Tags: python, canvas

I have the following code for jumping of polygon:

```
 def animate_up(canvas,id_rect,t,height_canvas,old_h_t=0): 
    if t<V_0/G: #jumping,max height
        #t+=0.001
        t+=(V_0/G)/20 #18=60*t-10*(0.5)*t^2 --> 36-120t+10t^2=0
        t=float(Decimal(str(t)).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_UP))
        new_h_t=V_0*t-G*(t**2)/2
        diff_h_t=new_h_t-old_h_t #diff heights
        canvas.move(id_rect,0,-diff_h_t)

        #spin rect
        if MODE=='SPIN': #spinning in the air
                #if t>1.5:
                   #exit()
                #else:
                spin(canvas,id_rect)
        
        root.after(15,lambda:animate_up(canvas,id_rect,t,height_canvas,new_h_t))
    else: #calc time to fall down and activate fall down
        t_to_fall=math.sqrt(old_h_t/(0.5*G))
        animate_down(canvas,id_rect,0,height_canvas,t_to_fall)

def animate_down(canvas,id_rect,t,height_canvas,t_to_fall,old_h_t=0):
    if t<t_to_fall: #falling
        t+=(V_0/G)/20
        t=float(Decimal(str(t)).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_UP))
        new_h_t=G*(t**2)/2
        h_t=new_h_t-old_h_t #diff heights  
        canvas.move(id_rect,0,h_t)
        if MODE=='SPIN': #spinning in the air
                spin(canvas,id_rect)
                
        root.after(15,lambda:animate_down(canvas,id_rect,t,height_canvas,t_to_fall,new_h_t))
    else:
        #fix small spin(?) error after placing on platform
        canvas.move(id_rect,0,467.5-canvas.coords(id_rect)[1])
```

let's say my parameters are:

```
G=15.0 
V_0=35
MODE=='NORMAL' #the spin part is not relevant to the question in the momemt
```

With these parameters the jumping seems normal,but if I want a higher jumping,let's say V_0=80,then the polygon starting to lose some of it's upper part of the shape (pixels) when it is near the highest point of the jumping.
Same thing happening when the object fall and is near the bottom of the platform,it starting to lose it's lower parts of the shape (pixels).

explain of arguments:

```
canvas- Canvas object
id_rect- id (int) of the polygon object that is drawn in my canvas
t=time #start jumping/falling t=0
height_canvas= height of my canvas #relevant to other part of the code that not shown here
old_h_t=height after using the jumping/falling formula
```

pictures to illustrate:

Upper part of the pentagon is missing near highest point of jumping
[image]

Lower part of the pentagon is missing near platform after falling(maybe it's hard to see but the change is from bottom edge):
[image]

How to fix this problem?
In addition,the jumping is very elastic,it seems that the object is stretching while jumping/falling,is there a way to change that?(maybe that's because of the illusion of missing parts?)

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: did you create this code or you copy it? Maybe this code crop object when it outside window. Maybe you should make all changes on original shape.

Comment: @furas I create this code. I tried print different things like y-coord of top vertex but it's not really helping.I tried on numerous regular polygons (3,4,5,6.. edges),all have this weird disappearing pixels and elastic movement.

Comment: print all `x,y` to see when it adds new point to polygon.

Comment: @furas Now when I add `print(canvas.coords(id_rect)[k])+','+str(canvas.coords(id_rect)[k+1]))` for all x,y coords of the polygon in the  `animate_up()` func after the line `canvas.move(id_rect,0,-diff_h_t)` , the polygon start to show correctly,although it's very slow and stuttering jumping.I start to think that it's because it doesn't have enought time to draw these pixels.How can I overcome this problem?